# jQuery box layout and animation

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a jQuery script/plugin that can do something like the 2 pictures attached where i tried to illustrate what i want.

I have a horisontal line with x amount of boxes:

[image]

When a user hovers or clicks a box, the selected box will expand across the prev and next box and show some alternative text - and when another boxes is choosen, the previous box is collapsed and the active box is shown with the alternative text etc:

[image]

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: And here is the two mentioned pictures;

1) http://i.stack.imgur.com/KO5Gi.png
2) http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvg87.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're looking for, but from the way I read it, you want something like a [horizontal accordion](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/horizontal-accordion). ([demo here](http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/))

Comment: There are a bunch of variants on that theme... try googling "jquery horizontal accordion" if that's close but not quite what you want.

Comment: Yeah, i though about and accordion - but the way i see it, in an accordion one box always has to be open? This is not the case in my request - when a user loads the page, all boxes are "closed" sort of speak - the box has 2 states. Closed and open - each one of them contains text etc, but the open one just contains some other text than in the "closed" state. Furthermore i want them to visually overlap when one i open - so the box that is open is visually overlapping the prev and next box, if any.

Comment: Accordions don't always have to have one box open. I've seen both types, but that's a fairly minor detail. I do have another question for you, though... in your example above, what would happen if box one was expanded? Would you want it to stretch to the left and right, or just to the right?

Comment: Good question :) Just to the right - and the last box should extent just to the left. :)

Comment: Nobody with further suggestions?